# Connecting Sensor Encoder Cb781-80006 to RPi

Tags: gpio, sensor

I need to connect Hp Sensor Encoder Cb781-80006 to my RPI I have an RPi 3 Model B+.

I use some recherche and I find this solution with Arduino but I have a problem with the outputs A-C I'm in trouble I'm trying to connect the two outputs one with the ground and the other with any GPIO pin but not working I think I do something wrong.

Thanks

[image]

**This is the image of a model I have**

[Sensor Encoder Cb781-8000](https://primelec.com/products/hp-officejet-replacement-sensor-encoder-board-cb781-80006)

Comment: this one? https://primelec.com/products/hp-officejet-replacement-sensor-encoder-board-cb781-80006

Comment: yes Cb781-80006

Comment: fake J4680 or the real thing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=025jjzz5tMk?

Comment: I will update the background of the pictures thank you jsotola

Comment: tlfong01 the link you give me is song ! can explean

Comment: Ah, sorry, try this one: http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/bpd06773.pdf

Comment: i got this message ( We can't find that page, but here's the good news - we've got other ways to find what you need)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119456/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-ma9).

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: can you explain why